# Find and delete from an array with multiple keys by search patterns

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am converting my PowerShell (PowerCLI) scripts into JavaScript ES5 codes so I can run them in vRealize Orchestrator. I am trying to find a list of VMs which are thin provisioned. In PowerCLI, I get an array of objects called "$result" with the following set of columns -

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------------+  
| VM             | Datastore     | Disk        | Size_GB | Thin | vCenter     |  
+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------------+  
| TLAPP021       | L03VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| TLSQL003-test  | L03VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| RLT00021       | L03VM2        | Hard Disk 2 | 90      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| RLTC0201       | local-L03     | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| TLAPP022       | L04VM1        | Hard Disk 3 | 140     | True | l04vcenter  |  
| TLAPP022-clone | L04VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 20      | True | l04vcenter  |  
| TLVMW023       | BRIDGE        | Hard Disk 5 | 90      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| RL000001       | TESTLAB       | Hard Disk 4 | 60      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| RLT00028       | L04VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l04vcenter  |  
| RLT00028-bku   | L04VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l04vcenter  |  
| TLADS007       | L03VM2        | Hard Disk 2 | 50      | True | l03vcenter  |  
+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------------+
```

which I then filter out based on "VM" not like such and such pattern -

```
$result | where-object {($_.VM -notlike "expand*") -and ($_.VM -notlike "*clone") -and ($_.VM -notlike "*bku") -and ($_.VM -notlike "*test")}
```

Then I filter out based on "Datastore" not like such and such pattern -

```
$result | where-object {($_.datastore -notlike "*local-*") -and ($_.datastore -notlike "[BRIDGE]*") -and ($_.datastore -notlike "[TESTLAB]*")}
```

And I end up with following objects in $result -

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------------+  
| VM             | Datastore     | Disk        | Size_GB | Thin | vCenter     |  
+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------------+  
| TLAPP021       | L03VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l03vcenter  |  
| RLT00021       | L03VM2        | Hard Disk 2 | 90      | True | l03vcenter  | 
| TLAPP022       | L04VM1        | Hard Disk 3 | 140     | True | l04vcenter  |  
| RLT00028       | L04VM1        | Hard Disk 1 | 40      | True | l04vcenter  |  
| TLADS007       | L03VM2        | Hard Disk 2 | 50      | True | l03vcenter  |  
+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------------+
```

I then sort my $result by "vCenter" first, then by "VM", then by "Datastore" and then by "Disk"

This is what I have come up with in JS for now -

```
var Result = [];
var vcs = VcPlugin.allSdkConnections;
for each(var vc in vcs) 
{
    var vms = vc.getAllVirtualMachines()
    for each(var vm in vms) 
    {
        var devices = vm.config.hardware.device;
        for each(var device in devices) 
        {
            if (device.deviceInfo.label.match(/Hard.*/))
            {
                if (device.backing.thinProvisioned)
                {
                    Result.push({
                        VM: vm.name,
                        Datastore: device.backing.fileName.split(" ")[0],
                        Disk: device.deviceInfo.label,
                        Size_GB: (device.capacityInKB/1048576).toFixed(2),
                        Thin: device.backing.thinProvisioned,
                        vCenter: vc.name.split(":")[1].substring(2)
                    });
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}

Result = Result.sort(function(a, b) 
{
    if(a.vCenter < b.vCenter)
    {
        return -1;  
    }
    else if(a.vCenter > b.vCenter)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(a.VM < b.VM)
        {
           return -1
        }
        else if(a.VM > b.VM)
        {
          return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a.Datastore < b.Datastore)
            {
               return -1
            }
            else if(a.Datastore > b.Datastore)
            {
              return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(a.Disk < b.Disk)
                {
                   return -1
                }
                else if(a.Disk > b.Disk)
                {
                  return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                  return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am struggling to filter stuff out of the "Result" variable with a pattern matching "VM" and "Datastore" keys.

I have searched many solutions but since it's in ES6 or newer version, it doesn't run in vRO. I need a ES5 compatible code.

Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't appear you are familiar with `.filter()` for arrays. Since 5.1: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20

Comment: I did try that out but it wouldn’t let me do pattern matching on multiple keys the easier way! If you can write it out and show, that would help!

Comment: I don't want to conjure the data structure - give me an array of objects to work with.

Comment: I just included the Array and the output in PowerCLI after filtering. How do I go about achieving this in JS ES5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is almost there (sort being in question). Note the use of [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for paring down the list with your two different sub-queries. Note also the use of [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) used for the string comparator in the sort functionality.

I am unclear on the expectation on the sorted results. If you provide the desired sorted output I can validate that I've achieved your goal.

The code is commented below:

```js
var VMSearchExp = ["^expand", "clone$", "bku$", "test$"];
var DatastoreExp = ["local-L03", "^BRIDGE", "^TESTLAB"];
var data = [
{VM:  "TLAPP021", Datastore: "L03VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLSQL003-test", Datastore: "L03VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLT00021", Datastore: "L03VM2",  Disk:"Hard Disk 2",Size_GB:90, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLTC0201", Datastore: "local-L03",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLAPP022", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 3",Size_GB:140, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLAPP022-clone", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:20, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLVMW023", Datastore: "BRIDGE",  Disk:"Hard Disk 5",Size_GB:90, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RL000001", Datastore: "TESTLAB",  Disk:"Hard Disk 4",Size_GB:60, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLT00028", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLT00028-bku", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLADS007", Datastore: "L03VM2",  Disk:"Hard Disk 2",Size_GB:50, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" }
];
// Clone the orginal
var dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
// Reduce the clone to exclude the VMSearchExps
dataCopy = VMSearchExp.reduce(function(acc,exp){dataCopy = dataCopy.filter(d=>!d.VM.match(exp)); return dataCopy}, VMSearchExp[0]);
console.log("Count 8: Originally 11: ",dataCopy);
// Reduce the clone to exclude the DatastoreExps
dataCopy = DatastoreExp.reduce(function(acc,exp){dataCopy = dataCopy.filter(d=>!d.Datastore.match(exp)); return dataCopy},DatastoreExp[0]);
console.log("Count 5: Originally 8: ",dataCopy);
// Sort: if any of a.[vCenter,VM,Datastore,Disk] comes before any of those in b -> promote it
result = dataCopy.sort(function(a,b) {
                         a.vCenter.localeCompare(b.vCenter) || 
                         a.VM.localeCompare(b.VM) || 
                         a.Datastore.localeCompare(b.Datastore) || 
                         a.Disk.localeCompare(b.Disk)
                        });
// Sorted result                        
console.log("Sorted: ",result);
```

Comment: "let" and "const" introduced since 2015 not in ES5. I am getting syntax error on -  

`let dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`  

if replaced with "var", Getting syntax error on next line as well -   

`dataCopy = VMSearchExp.reduce((acc,exp)=>{dataCopy = dataCopy.filter(d=>!d.VM.match(exp)); return dataCopy}, VMSearchExp[0]);`  

I don't think arrows are part of ES5 as well

Comment: Habit - I'll fix.

Comment: That should do it. Please let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Randy! I used Bable to convert your code to ES5 and with some optimization this worked -

```
var VMSearchExp = ["^expand", "clone$", "bku$", "test$"];
var DatastoreExp = ["^local", "^BRIDGE", "^TESTLAB"];
var data = [
{VM:  "TLAPP021", Datastore: "L03VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLSQL003-test", Datastore: "L03VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLT00021", Datastore: "L03VM2",  Disk:"Hard Disk 2",Size_GB:90, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLTC0201", Datastore: "local-L03",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLAPP022", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 3",Size_GB:140, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLAPP022-clone", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:20, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLVMW023", Datastore: "BRIDGE",  Disk:"Hard Disk 5",Size_GB:90, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RL000001", Datastore: "TESTLAB",  Disk:"Hard Disk 4",Size_GB:60, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLT00028", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "RLT00028-bku", Datastore: "L04VM1",  Disk:"Hard Disk 1",Size_GB:40, Thin: true, vCenter: "l04vcenter" },
{VM:  "TLADS007", Datastore: "L03VM2",  Disk:"Hard Disk 2",Size_GB:50, Thin: true, vCenter: "l03vcenter" }
];

var dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

dataCopy = VMSearchExp.reduce(function (acc,exp) 
{
    dataCopy = dataCopy.filter(function (d) 
    {
        return !d.VM.match(exp);
    })
    return dataCopy;
}, VMSearchExp[0]);

dataCopy = DatastoreExp.reduce(function (acc,exp)
{
    dataCopy = dataCopy.filter(function (d)
    {
        return !d.Datastore.match(exp);
    })
    return dataCopy;
}, DatastoreExp[0]);

var result = dataCopy.sort(function (a,b)
{
    return a.vCenter.localeCompare(b.vCenter) || 
    a.VM.localeCompare(b.VM) || 
    a.Datastore.localeCompare(b.Datastore) || 
    a.Disk.localeCompare(b.Disk);
});
```

Here's the output -

```
[INFO] Input:
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP021 Datastore:- L03VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLSQL003-test Datastore:- L03VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00021 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 90 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLTC0201 Datastore:- local-L03 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP022 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 3 Size_GB:- 140 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP022-clone Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 20 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLVMW023 Datastore:- BRIDGE Disk:- Hard Disk 5 Size_GB:- 90 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RL000001 Datastore:- TESTLAB Disk:- Hard Disk 4 Size_GB:- 60 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00028 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00028-bku Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLADS007 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 50 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] Count 8: Originally 11: 
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP021 Datastore:- L03VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00021 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 90 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLTC0201 Datastore:- local-L03 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP022 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 3 Size_GB:- 140 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLVMW023 Datastore:- BRIDGE Disk:- Hard Disk 5 Size_GB:- 90 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RL000001 Datastore:- TESTLAB Disk:- Hard Disk 4 Size_GB:- 60 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00028 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLADS007 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 50 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] Count 5: Originally 8: 
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP021 Datastore:- L03VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00021 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 90 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP022 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 3 Size_GB:- 140 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00028 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLADS007 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 50 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] Sorted: 
[INFO] VM:- RLT00021 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 90 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLADS007 Datastore:- L03VM2 Disk:- Hard Disk 2 Size_GB:- 50 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP021 Datastore:- L03VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l03vcenter
[INFO] VM:- RLT00028 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 1 Size_GB:- 40 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
[INFO] VM:- TLAPP022 Datastore:- L04VM1 Disk:- Hard Disk 3 Size_GB:- 140 Thin:- true vCenter:- l04vcenter
 => undefined
```